# terminal api not working on gvim

Tags: gvim, terminal, microsoft-windows, terminal-buffer

vim 8 support terminal, and has a api to let command in terminal to communicate back to vim.

**For example:**

In vim, define function like

```
" .vimrc
let g:cnt = get(g:, 'cnt', 0)
func! Tapi_Command_finish(bufnum, arglist) abort
    let g:cnt += 1
endfunc " Tapi_Command_finish
```

open a terminal buffer, run command

```
printf '\033]51;["call","Tapi_%s", ["%s"]]\007' Command_finish
```

then go back to vim, `:echo g:cnt`, `1` will be echoed, demonstrate function `Tapi_Command_finish` being called.

This works in linux, **but when i tried on windows gvim 8, it did not work.**

I search around, some say `cmd` do not support ansi escape sequence. (not sure if `\033]51...` is ansi escape sequence or not.)

The question:

Is there a way to use terminal api on windows gvim?

== **EDIT** == (The echo part)

Below are 3 ways I can thought of to reproduce the echo part.

- 1 cat file approach

under posix shell, eg, cygwin

```
printf '\033]51;["call","Tapi_%s", ["%s"]]\007' Command_finish > xx
```

and `cp` or `scp` to current directory. then in terminal buffer

```
type xx
```

- 2 use python

create file `yy.py`, with content

```
print('\033]51;["call","Tapi_%s", ["%s"]]\007' % ("Command_finish",""))
```

then in terminal buffer, run

```
python yy.py
```

- 3 use `echo`

not tried, since I don't know how to reliably send '\033'.

Of the 3 ways, both 1 & 2 works on cygwin.

Comment: Which command did you use in Windows cmd? `echo`? I guess that's perhaps one of the most important parts to reproducing your issue...

Comment: @filbranden, have edited the question to add description about `echo part`.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, what do you mean by "works on cygwin"... Do you mean if you have a `:terminal` window and run Cygwin bash there? But it doesn't work if `:terminal` is running cmd.exe? Not even the Python one? (I'd expect it would behave similarly on Cygwin and on Windows)... Or by "on cygwin" do you mean running Vim *from* cygwin inside the cygwin shell, in which case the `:terminal` window will be a Posix shell I'd expect?

Comment: I mean use cygwin mintty itself, independent of gvim, just like regular unix terminal. BTW, I don't know to use other terminal under windows gvim.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Windows world is indeed a bit foreign to me so I don't really know the details of Windows terminal and how Vim's `:terminal` works there... It's a good question, hopefully you'll get a good answer for it!

Answer (score 1):

So [`:help terminal-communication`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-communication) lists `term_sendkeys()`, then the JSON API you can access with the escape sequence, then finally:

> Use the `client-server` mechanism. This works on machines with an X server *and on MS-Windows*.

I'm not sure if that's meant to say that the other mechanisms will *not* work on MS-Windows, but at least they're saying this one *should* work there.

Then [`:help terminal-client-server`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-client-server) describes that in more detail. You need to have your Vim instance register a server name (which it might do automatically, but you might need to do yourself.) Then, when you open a new `:terminal`, the server name will be available in an environment variable, `$VIM_SERVERNAME` (I believe this will be the case in `cmd.exe` as well, though probably it will be `%VIM_SERVERNAME%` there.)

From there, you can call a `gvim --remote` command, to either open a file on that Vim server, or to actually evaluate an expression or send keystrokes to be executed.

The exame from the help page, opening a file:

```
vim --servername $VIM_SERVERNAME --remote +123 some_file.c
```

But you'll probably want to look into [`:help --remote-expr`](https://vimhelp.org/remote.txt.html#--remote-expr) (and possibly `--remote-send` as well.)

Note that this mechanism is *a lot more powerful* than the JSON API, since you can use it to evaluate arbitrary expressions, call arbitrary functions, send keystrokes. It's also synchronous and bidirectional, since you can evaluate expressions and get their result from the command running on the terminal.

On the other hand, it's heavier (need to invoke the Vim binary), less portable and might require some setup (ensuring the server is running and has a server name set.)

Having said that, you might want to consider that as an option, since it seems to be perfectly suited for the environment you're on.

Comment: Thx, I tried `--remote-expr`, which solved my problem. The caveat is needing to spawn vim to just send some message. But it works, that's enough. Thx for your help, I didn't realize `vim server` can be used here. Upvoted, but not accept since I leave it to terminal api approach, but it might be a long time before it being implemented.